# How to make touchpad settings stick on Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Trusty)

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, macbook

We've installed Trusty on a 2008 MacBook 4,1 as the sole OS for the machine. The install went off without a hitch; however the touchpad was frustrating to use.

We were able to correct for this by changing the touchpad settings via the command line using:

```
synclient FingerLow = 10
synclient FingerHigh = 20
```

These settings are great, but they reset every time the machine is shut down.

We've looked through all the documentation we could find; however in this case, none of it seemed helpful. We are running stock Trusty LTS with the stock Unity desktop.

**Question:** Who knows how to get these settings to stick.

Comment: I just noticed you answered your own question instead of leaving a comment...  This means I was never notified of your "comment" If this is still relevant, press "[add comment] and leave a comment "@Fabby"...  **:-(**

Comment: Sorry, Fabby. still a bit new around these parts.

Comment: No worries...  Does it work now???  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the dash
2. Type `gedit` and click the icon
3. Copy-paste the following text into it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   synclient FingerLow = 10
   synclient FingerHigh = 20
   ```
4. Save the file in your home directory in the `bin` directory calling it `TouchPadFix.sh`
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following command: `chmod +x ~/bin/TouchPadFix.sh`
6. Go back to the dash
7. Type `startup`
8. Click `Startup Applications`
9. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>
10. Enter in the command field: `TouchPadFix.sh` and type in <kbd>Name</kbd> and <kbd>Comment</kbd> whatever you want (Don't leave it empty)
11. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>

### That's it!

Next time you reboot the settings will be sticky!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Fabby. This ended up working out. I've a lot more GNU/Linux miles logged at this point and things are working out well. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: :D  That's about a year ago!  Well, enjoy the solution and thanks for the upvote!